# Mac PyInstaller FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I try to build a standalone app with PyInstaller but I don't manage to do it when I add images to my app.

My `.exe file` works well when I don't include the `.ico, .jpg, .png` but when I inclue it, it doesn't work anymore (`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Pictures/picture.png'`).

I tried to modify the `--path` option (I tried with the `"main.py" path` and also with `"." path` but it makes nothing.

My app uses `Tkinter` and `Pillow` for the images.

**Interesting fact :** I tried to run my `.exe file` with a copy of my picture files in `user/username/pictures/` and it works. But I can't create a standalone app like that.

Mac version : 11.2.1

Python version : 3.8.5

Comment: Have you tried py2app for OSX: https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: But for a long-term solution I would look into the kivvy app framework which is built on top of pyinstaller for desktop packaging preventing any nasty  glitches

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you

Comment: Its always a pleasure

Comment: Im working on an official answer to post here in the next day